# Offset in GeoTIFF coordinates Google Earth Engine extracts

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, google-earth-engine

I download a certain geographic location (lon,lat) with buffer radius around for MODIS products, such as MCD43A2/MCD43A4 from Google Earth Engine using ee, such as:

```
 lon = 10.452175
 lat = 51.079206
 product = 'MODIS/006/MCD43A4'
 sensor = product.split('/')[-1]
 radius = 2000
 res = 500
 start,end = (datetime(2004, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime(2004, 12, 31, 23, 59))


geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).buffer(radius)
col      = ee.ImageCollection(product)
features = col.filterDate(start, end).getInfo()['features']

http = urllib3.PoolManager(num_pools=10,
                            cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
                            ca_certs=certifi.where())


for feature in features:
    url = ee.Image(feature['id']).clip(geometry).getDownloadURL()
    #request.urlretrieve(url,OutDir.format(site_id,sensor)+feature['id'].split('/')[-1]+'.zip')
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    with open(OutDir.format(site_id,sensor)+feature['id'].split('/')[-1]+'.zip', "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.data)
```

than I get, using `gdalinfo 2004_01_06.Nadir_Reflectance_Band1.tif` :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2004_01_06.Nadir_Reflectance_Band1.tif
Size is 10, 10
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["MODIS Sinusoidal",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (727864.277675088495016,5682067.155503926798701)
Pixel Size = (463.312716528000010,-463.312716527000021)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  727864.278, 5682067.156) ( 10d25'45.53"E, 51d16'10.18"N)
Lower Left  (  727864.278, 5677434.028) ( 10d25'11.63"E, 51d13'40.26"N)
Upper Right (  732497.405, 5682067.156) ( 10d29'44.52"E, 51d16'10.18"N)
Lower Right (  732497.405, 5677434.028) ( 10d29'10.41"E, 51d13'40.26"N)
Center      (  730180.841, 5679750.592) ( 10d27'28.01"E, 51d14'55.22"N)
Band 1 Block=10x10 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

This does not refer to the input I made:
'lon = 10.452175, lat = 51.079206'
at least for latitude.

How can I get around this, retrieving the original (projection) data subset, not re-projected, with the center (lon,lat) in the center of the subset? Or which would be the correct transformation to e done?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some progress, changing GEE outputed geo.parameters. See the processing chain below:

Input coordinate:
`10.453 51.07916667`

gdalinfo on GEE extracted:

```
  Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
  Files: 2000_06_22.BRDF_Albedo_ValidObs_Band1.tif
  Size is 10, 10
  Coordinate System is:
  PROJCS["MODIS Sinusoidal",
      GEOGCS["WGS 84",
          DATUM["WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                  AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
          UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
      PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
      PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
      UNIT["metre",1,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
  Origin = (727864.277675088495016,5682067.155503926798701)
  Pixel Size = (463.312716528000010,-463.312716527000021)
  Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=BAND
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (  727864.278, 5682067.156) ( 10d25'45.53"E, 51d16'10.18"N)
  Lower Left  (  727864.278, 5677434.028) ( 10d25'11.63"E, 51d13'40.26"N)
  Upper Right (  732497.405, 5682067.156) ( 10d29'44.52"E, 51d16'10.18"N)
  Lower Right (  732497.405, 5677434.028) ( 10d29'10.41"E, 51d13'40.26"N)
  Center      (  730180.841, 5679750.592) ( 10d27'28.01"E, 51d14'55.22"N)
  Band 1 Block=10x10 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Grayi
```

Change the flattening.geo.key in idl and save in tmp.tif

```
  tiff = read_tiff('2000_06_22.BRDF_Albedo_ValidObs_Band1.tif', geo=geo)
  % Loaded DLM: TIFF.
  IDL> geo.GEOGINVFLATTENINGGEOKEY = 0
  IDL> write_tiff,'tmp.tif', tiff, geotiff = geo
```

you can also edit the geoinformation of the *.tif with gdal_edit.py

```
gdal_edit.py -a_srs '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs' tmp.tif
```

gdalwarp with the original MODIS projection parameters

```
  gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r near tmp.tif out.tif
  Creating output file that is 15P x 8L.
  Processing input file tmp.tif
  0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

checking the output:

```
gdalinfo out.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out.tif
Size is 15, 8
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (10.414531289201173,51.099999995476345)
Pixel Size = (0.004987355776781,-0.004987355776781)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2019:07:11 10:28:07
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=tmp.tif
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IDL 8.5.1, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc., a subsidiary of Harris Corporation.
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  10.4145313,  51.1000000) ( 10d24'52.31"E, 51d 6' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (  10.4145313,  51.0601011) ( 10d24'52.31"E, 51d 3'36.36"N)
Upper Right (  10.4893416,  51.1000000) ( 10d29'21.63"E, 51d 6' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (  10.4893416,  51.0601011) ( 10d29'21.63"E, 51d 3'36.36"N)
Center      (  10.4519365,  51.0800506) ( 10d27' 6.97"E, 51d 4'48.18"N)
Band 1 Block=15x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

`10.453 51.07916667`